# 1950s or earlier book with electrical currents living on Pluto

Tags: story-identification, books

My first sci-fi book I ever read was in the early 1950's in Europe (probably 1952) and it had 10 stories about a different form of life on every planet, including the sun. All I can really remember is that the life on the sun was organized plasma streams on the sun's outer layers, and the life on Pluto was permanent electrical currents within lakes of liquid helium on the planet's surface. Very imaginative at the time.

Comment: Three old stories about plasma life on the Sun are Clarke's "Castaway" and "Out of the Sun", and Clement's "Proof". I don't know any stories that old about electrical life on Pluto.

Comment: It’s too late to be the answer, but Larry Niven had superconductor-based life on Pluto in his early short story ”Wait It Out”

Comment: The Niven one is way later than 1952.

Comment: @MikeScott: I think you should post that as an answer; it seems that the OP has conflated two things, one of which is very likely to be the Larry Niven short story you mention.

Comment: The idea of life as electric currents in seas of liquid helium is used by Arthur C. Clarke in his story ["Crusade"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/187696/19561) (1968). You can [listen to it on YouTube](https://youtu.be/Li0TnrRTmM8).

Answer (score 15):

That is *[Flight into Space](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?13974)* edited by Don Wollheim and published in 1950 by Frederick Fell.

It's subtitled "*Great Science-Fiction Stories of Interplanetary Travel*" and just as you describe, has a story for the Sun, all nine planets, the Moon and the asteroids.  The Sun creatures (in [*Sunward*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?70756) by Stanton A. Coblentz) are as you said, but the Plutonians ([*The Rape of the Solar System*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?70749) by Leslie F. Stone) were not -- in that story Pluto was located closer to the Sun until a war with Mars hurtled it outwards.

[image]

Comment: Great find! These are really old stories.